# Cosa significa "sopratono"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Risposi volentieri: era la prima volta che qualcuno m’interrogava sulla mia amicizia con lei e ne parlai per tutto il tragitto con grande entusiasmo. Fu anche la prima volta che sentii come, dovendo cercare le parole per un tema per il quale non avevo parole pronte, tendessi a ridurre il rapporto tra me e Lila ad affermazioni tutte **sopratono** e di esclamativa positività.

Non capisco il significato di "sopratono" in questo brano. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Ho visto che questo termine, "sopratono", appare più avanti nel libro in quest'altro passaggio:

> «Ha giurato fedeltà a mia madre davanti a Dio» esclamò di colpo **sopratono**. «Non rispetta né lei né Dio». E balzò su tutto agitato, aveva occhi bellissimi e lucenti.

Comment: Credo che venga dal lessico musicale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il significato della parola sopratono è "ad un tono più alto del normale".
Nella prima frase la parola viene usata per indicare uno stile esagerato, nella seconda invece si riferisce al tono della voce, ovvero all'intensità dei suoni emessi.

Anche se la parola non compare in molti dizionari, il significato mi sembra evidente e non credo ci siano altre possibili interpretazioni.

Certamente non è un termine di uso comune.
È interessante vedere in [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sopratono%2Csottotono&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csopratono%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csottotono%3B%2Cc0) come l'uso di **sopratono** sia in qualche modo correlato a quello del più comune vocabolo **sottotono**. Probabilmente viene usato spontaneamente come opposto di quest'ultimo, che viene riportato da diversi dizionari.

Answer (score 2):

Ecco la definizione di "sopratono" che appare sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000469.jpg):

> **Sopratono** (*sopratuòno*), sm. Intonazione della voce 
>   più alta del normale. 
>       *De Sanctis*, *Lett. it.*,
>    II-179: Essendo il proprio di questa ma­niera  una cantilena breve e chiusa,...  vi  si  sviluppa  l’elemento cantabile  e  musicale,  una  enfasi  sonora,  un  suono  di  tromba 
>   perpetuo  e  monotono,  con  certe  pause,  con  certi  strilli,  con certe  ripigliate,  con  un  certo  sopratuono  come  di  chi  gridi  e 
>   non  parli. *Cassieri*, 126:  «Giorni  e  notti  a  pensare  a  un  mio costumino?» si difese con un sopratono malizioso. 
>       **2.**  Modo  di  comportarsi  o  atteggiamento  che  oltre­passa la misura o la convenienza. 
>       *N. Boni*  [«Stampa  Sera»,  28-X-1985],  6:  Questa  Serena Grandi  non  la  si  mette  proprio  in  imbarazzo.  Entusiasta,  ma senza  sopratoni.  Ha  imparato  cosa  chiedere  alla  vita  ed  esser­ne contenta. 
>       = Comp. da 
>   *sopra* e *tono* (v.).

L'uso che se ne fa nella prima frase della domanda corrisponde alla seconda accezione del dizionario, invece quello della seconda frase fa riferimento alla prima accezione.

Comment: La cosa curiosa è che nel dizionario è un sostantivo, mentre nei testi della domanda sembra essere usato come un aggettivo e un avverbio. Ho trovato questo termine in una commedia di Dario Fo in cui, nella battuta che fa dire a un personaggio, specifica tra parentesi "sopratono": mi pare anche un uso avverbiale o aggettivale.